# Scala, type of constructor currying

Tags: scala, typeclass, currying

I just wrote Matrix class, with following constuctor:

```
class Matrix (val dim1: Int)(val dim2: Int, val args: Matrix.IntMode*)
```

So, i want to get an vector class, which first dimension is always 1, and try something like that:

```
  type Vector = Matrix(1) _
```

But cant find correct way to implement my idea. I will appreciate for any help with this

Answer (score 4):

How about the following:

```
class A(val a: Int)(b: Int, c: Int)
class B(b: Int, c: Int) extends A(1)(b,c) {
  override def toString = s"$a $b $c"
}
val b = new B(3, 4)
println(b)
```

This produces the following when run in a Scala worksheet:

```
1 3 4
```

I had to make the parameter `a` into a `val` so it would be visible to `b` for the `toString`

Comment: Your solution look pretty good, but i was hoping that i can find easy scala-way solution with types and currying. Anyway, lot of thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend **mattinbits** solution.

Though, if you do not want to define another class, you could achieve something like that with:

```
type Vector = Matrix
object Vector {
  def apply(dim2: Int, args: Matrix.IntMode*): Vector = new Matrix(1)(dim2, args: _*)
}

val myVector = Vector(2, ...)
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, sir!